# how to inject dependency into a custom control

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am using Dependency Injection to Inject interface into my few views. One of the requirement I need to Inject the interface into the custom control. I have tried using ServiceDependency attribute to inject interface , but it doesn't work.

```
public interface ISearchService
{
    void CustomizeLayout(ColumnCollection collection);
}
IService _service;

[ServiceDependency]
public IService Service
{
    get
    {
        return _service;
    }
    set
    {
        _service = value;
    }
}
```

then i m calling Service.CustomizeLayout(this.Columns) in my custom control. It throws Object ref not set to instance of an object (Service comes as a null).

Can somebody tell me wat could be the problem or how to inject dependency into a control similar way which we do for the win forms.

Comment: sorry i m not aware of 0% accpet rate? what is this

Comment: @Punit Singhi: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

Comment: Which technology are you asking about? Windows Forms? ASP.NET? Which DI Container?

Comment: we are using CAB application using C#. Yeah it is about DI container.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used CAB so forgive me if I got you wrong. Your problem is probably that the custom control ist not created by CAB and CAB is not aware of the control having dependencies when it creates the view containing the control. I remember having the problem, too but can't recall the exact solution :-(

Comment: yeah this is the exact problem, i m trying to find it out, just one thing can we add controls as items collection of workitem.